# Melt or Stack groups of columns on python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like this

```
year  id1  id2  jan jan1 jan2 feb feb1 feb2 mar mar1 mar2 ....
2018   01   10    3   30   31   2   23   25   7   52   53 ....
2018   01   20    ....
2018   02   10    ....
2018   02   20    ....
```

and I need this format

```
year month id1 id2 val val1 val2
2018    01  01  10   3   30   31
2018    02  01  10   2   23   25
2018    03  01  10   7   52   53
..........
```

As you can see, I have 3 values for each month, and I only add one column assigned to the month with 3 columns for the values. If it were only one column, I think I could use `stack`.

I wouldn't have any problem renaming the month columns to `01  01-1  01-2` (for january) or something like that to make it easier.

I'm also thinking on separating the info on 3 different DataFrames to `stack` them separately and then `merge` the results, or should I `melt` it?

Any ideas for achieving this easily?

Comment: Have you considered simply looping over the first dataframe while you reformat the data and use that reformatted data to create the second dataframe? It's brute force, but very clear.

Comment: [The Pandas user guide on reshaping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt) gives several example using `melt` (easier to rename the  “variable” and “value” columns) or `stack` (designed to work together with MultiIndex objects).

Answer (score 1):

using `reshape` and `stack`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.set_index(['year','id1','id2']).values.reshape(4,3,3).tolist(),
index=df.set_index(['year','id1','id2']).index,
     columns=[1,2,3])\
       .stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3':'month'})

Out[261]: 
    year  id1  id2  month  0   1   2
0   2018    1   10      1  3  30  31
1   2018    1   10      2  2  23  25
2   2018    1   10      3  7  52  53
3   2018    1   20      1  3  30  31
4   2018    1   20      2  2  23  25
5   2018    1   20      3  7  52  53
6   2018    2   10      1  3  30  31
7   2018    2   10      2  2  23  25
8   2018    2   10      3  7  52  53
9   2018    2   20      1  3  30  31
10  2018    2   20      2  2  23  25
11  2018    2   20      3  7  52  53
```

Answer (score 0):

So I renamed the header columns this way

```
                 01   01   01  02   02   02  03   03   03  ...
year  id1  id2  val val1 val2 val val1 val2 val val1 val2 ....
2018   01   10    3   30   31   2   23   25   7   52   53 ....
2018   01   20    ....
2018   02   10    ....
2018   02   20    ....
```

on a file, and opened it this way

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv',header=[0, 1], index_col=[0,1,2], skipinitialspace=True, tupleize_cols=True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

then, I actually only needed to `stack` it on level 0

```
df = df.stack(level=0)
```

and add the titles

```
df.index.names = ['year','id1','id2','month']
df = df.reset_index()
```